# h2o + r + flow Integration

Tags: h2o, sparkling-water

I am trying to connect to Sparkling Water using R and also analyze my data frames on the H20 flow. I could connect to Spark instance from R using sparkly and sparklingR package and generate a few H20 dataframes. Please advise how can I access the Flow using the same Spark context as created by the spark_connect.
Using the following versions

1. H2o Flow 3.0.4.7
2. R v. 3.4
3. R Studio version v. 1.0.143
4. Sparkling Water v. 2.1.0
5. Spark  v. 2.1.0

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

`h2o_flow(sc, strict_version_check = TRUE)`, where sc is the spark context you created.

You can also see the address of flow using `h2o.clusterInfo()`.